# How to calculate $f(x)$ from exponential function in graph?

Tags: exponential-function, graphing-functions

Given an exponential graph image of $f(x)$, how do you calculate $f(x)$?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are native ways to fit the function as noted in this posts. Logarithmic transformations will distort the problem.

[Least squares solution for $y=ax^{b}$ after logarithmic transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670654/least-squares-solution-for-y-axb-after-logarithmic-transformation/2241027#2241027)

[Linearize $y=c +ax^{b}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941193/linearize-y-caxb/2221717#2221717)

[Least Square Approximation for Exponential Functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1488747/least-square-approximation-for-exponential-functions/2163333#2163333)

---

Suppose you want to use the functional form $y=ae^{bx}$.

From the boundary point $(0,4)$, we know $a=4$. Now solve for $b$ using the second endpoint $(10,24)$:
$$
4 e^{10b} = 24
$$
to find
$$
b = \frac{\ln 6}{10}
$$

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using a calculator at all?

Comment: @Valentina: Do you have a functional form? Your plot provides some boundary points $(0,4)$, $(10,24)$. If you have an exponential form with two or three parameters you might make a decent guess.

Comment: No functional form at all sadly!

Comment: @Valentina: Readers are curious. Can you exactly state the question you were asked? Essential context seems absent.

Comment: This is ALL the information I have!

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much! This is exactly what I meant. My maths sucks so much now D:

Comment: "without using a calculator at all": are you kidding ? This is not humanly doable by hand.

Answer (score 0):

If it is exponential then you can use the logarithms to fit a line since $\ln(e^x) = x$.

Comment: Would you mind explaining through the calculation for me please? I know if y = Ae^bx that ln(y) = bx + ln(A) but I don't know how to calculate it from the graph!